# Example AwsCredentials.properties for SES SMTP / AWS Java

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

The Java Code example is all over the web.  But where is an example of the properties file contents `AwsCredentials.properties`?

```
public AmazonSESMailer(Environment env) throws IOException {
    this.env = env;
    InputStream resource = AmazonSESMailer.class
            .getResourceAsStream("/AwsCredentials.properties");
    PropertiesCredentials credentials = new PropertiesCredentials(resource);
    this.client = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient(credentials);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "aws");
    props.setProperty("mail.aws.user", credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId());
    props.setProperty("mail.aws.password", credentials.getAWSSecretKey());
    this.session = Session.getInstance(props);
}

private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(AmazonSESMailer.class);
private final static String FROM = "vraptor.simplemail.main.from";
private final static String REPLY_TO = "vraptor.simplemail.main.replyTo";
private final static String SEND_REAL_EMAIL = "vraptor.simplemail.send_real_email";
```

Answer (score 1):

The getResourceAsStream("/AwsCredentials.properties") file is being loaded by the class loader, so put it in the "classes" folder of the web app.  Then the contents of the file should be only two lines:

accessKey = UTZA...
secretKey =  Alj...

enjoy